# OpenShift Origin PHP missing MySQL extension

Tags: paas, openshift-origin

I have installed OpenShift Origin on my VPS, with a fresh minimal CentOS installation.

Now I'm trying to deploy a wordpress instance to run a blog, and I followed a blog post to use these commands.

```
rhc app create wordpress php-5.4 mysql-5.5 --fromcode=https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example
git add *
git commit -m init
```

And the upload process finished without any error.

```
Your application 'wordpress' is now available.

URL:        http://******/
SSH to:     ******@******
Git remote: ssh://******@******/~/git/wordpress.git/     Cloned to:  /Users/amphineko/Temp/wordpress
```

Then when I access the URL provided above (http://******/), it tells me there's something wrong.

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
```

But I tried to add a phpmyadmin cartridge under the same application via the web console and access it, it works fine.

Is there something wrong with my configuration of Wordpress, like defining the requirement of MySQL extension?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a "phpinfo" page and see what extensions it says are loaded. Also make sure you have the correct mysql extension installed for the version of the php cartridge you are using. It is possible that the phpmyadmin cartridge is using a different version of php installed on your server than your php cartridge.